# Crypto library that implements SHA-3 using ACLE Intrinsics

Tags: cryptography, ssl, arm

I'm looking for a library that implements SHA-3 using ACLE intrinsics that fall-backs to inline assembly for older versions of compilers that hasn't supported SHA-3 & SHA-512 intrinsics yet. I think it's some version of mbed-tls receiving contribution from ARM but I'm not sure.